# How to get ip address of client producing TCP half open connections?

Tags: java, networking, tcp

There is a server listening incoming connections to a given port. Suppose server is 172.16.5.26 and port is 4099. When I scanned this as

```
nmap 172.16.5.26 -p 4099
```

I'm able to get the ip address of client. But when TCP half open connection is requested as

```
nmap -sS 172.16.5.26 -p 4099
```

I'm unable to get the IP address of client. I'm looking for a method in java to do this task. If there is no such inbuilt method in java library, is there any way to accomplish the task ?

Comment: @tendua, your question assumes that people must be familiar not only with java but also with nmap command line. Could you please explain better what do you need, so that guys could understand you without reading the nmap man pages?

Comment: @AlexR: I used nmap only to produce requests to server. First command simply produces full TCP connection while second command produces TCP half open connection. Anything which could do this is suitable. I used nmap just to make it short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.getRemoteAddess() and friends. But these assume the connection is to your JVM and that this is the corresponding socket. If you're looking for a Java method to find arbitrary half open connections anywhere in the host there isn't one.

What's the motivation here? Why do you need this?

Comment: I wasn't aware that identifying SYN flood attack is a difficult thing.

Comment: @I didn't say it was difficult, but it remains impossible in Java except under the conditions I cited. But then you didn't say that's what you were attempting either. It would have been useful to allude to it in your question.